# Difference between scope = {} and scope = $rootScope.$new() in Angular unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I notice that there are two approaches, when setting controller's unit tests - **scope = {}** and  **scope = $rootScope.$new()**

What I need to know is the reasoning for choosing one over the other. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any explanation why one is used and the other is not.

I suppose, that *scope = {}* will be faster, but is there any other advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call methods on the scope such as `.$watch` or anything else, they need to be defined on the `scope` object that you are using.  `{}` (empty object) has no such methods, but `$rootScope.$new` does.

If you don't need to use such methods it doesn't actually matter what you use, and you could stub or define those methods on an object and inject that as the scope as well. It depends on what you need for your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you fix the typo on "call methods no the"?